# How can I ensure a chubby spawn?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've played a few hours between two characters having never seen a chubby monster spawn anywhere (as far as I recall anyway) and then I ran into two during my first trip to the caustic caverns with my second character.

They seem to drop decent loot and the two I saw were pretty easy to defeat. Is there a reliable way to spawn these cute things so I can murder them for epic guns?

Comment: @ authenticgeek I found a chubby skag by the happy pig motel early on my first playthrough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chubbies have a small chance of spawning from pre-set locations I believe. So if you revisit the areas that might have them repeatedly you might see one. They're extremely rare though. Two known spawn locations are:

- Right outside Hero's Pass, in the Eridian Blight. There's a Chubby Rakk. I've seen this one myself. I have also been in this area about 100 times looking for Donkey Mong and never saw a second one (or Donkey Mong) so the rate seems to be very very low.
- Right inside the Caustic Caverns there's a Chubby Varkid spawn location. I've gone through this area maybe 2-3 dozen times? And never seen it.

I wouldn't bother *actively* seeking these guys. As with most "rare" things in Borderlands 2, they're *far* too rare to make actively hunting them any fun. For the record I'm at over 150 hours game time and I've seen *one*. Allegedly the caustic caverns one is easy to make appear but I've never tried seeking it out.

Interestingly there's a *lot* of Chubby Rakk that spawn in an area in the Tourge DLC in a specific area (the only Rakk in the whole DLC, a mission takes you to the area). These Chubby Rakk seem to be a 100% spawn but don't drop the special look (or if they do it's an extremely low rate). I killed about 10 of them with no drops beyond ammo/cash.

Comment: You've only seen one?  I've played a third as much as you and have seen at least 2 (a skag and a rakk).  Mind you, both times I was playing with my brother, so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @MBraedley I mostly play in coop as well, but yeah, just a single one. But like I said, they're near fixed spawn points, so if you wander by those points a lot it's possible you've found them more often

Comment: I had the chubby spawn in Caustic Caverns when I was searching for the treasure room hidden in the level for one of the quests.  The location is just outside the infested warehouse in the area where the threshers spawn.  I think it's near a dump truck.

Answer (score 2):

I ve seen quite a lot for a while in frost burn canyon as chubby spider ants but it was on a reset ultimate vault hunter after pack 2 came out but I done it solo and that was three four chub buys then in wildlife preserve and also chubby varkids in tundra express and caustic caverns mainly in stead of badass evolutions (probably the easiest way to get them).

Answer (score 1):

A good place to for me was caustic caverns. I've found at least 10 chubbies and have gotten Vermiverous the Invincible or whatever his name is twice and have gotten orange loot. Hint though: more players means a higher spawn rate of these enemies.

I play system link with two brothers and dad. We have gotten a ton of ultimate varkids in caustic caverns. All you do is get the varkids to attack the crystalisk since they can't kill each other. Then you just sit in the cave at the beginning, keeping the varkids in combat mode so pods timer does not reset. What I mean by the timer is that a regular small varkid does not take long to go into pod form, adult takes a bit longer, bad*** takes longer, and so forth.

As long as they are noted on your mini map as red dots during the mutation process, you should be able to keep them mutating! Best to have three wait at the beginning of Caustic Cavern's and one player lead the varkids to the crystalisk and wait in the cave. Then you sit and let the varkids mutate. The higher the level of varkid such as super or ultimate, the lower they will go into pod form and the longer the time it takes for them to. I don't play the game that much and have gotten all this.

Remember; more players, better spawns. It's also good to have the rare loot relic from the Mechromancer DLC. That helps me out a lot. Hope this helps you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I have slain many chubbies, I didn't think they were so rare. They don't spawn very often, but they have been murdered at places such as:

- The Caustic Caverns, where chubby Spiderants and chubby Varkids have spawned.  They seem to sometimes spawn instead of Superbadass Varkids when they morph on occasion.
- There have been some chubby Stalkers at the Wildlife Exploitation Preserve.
- Chubby Rakk in the Fridge instead of the Badass Rakk.
- Chubby Skags have spawned in Three Horns Valley (very rarely, as in only ever seen one)
- Chubby Spiderants have been seen at the Dust, behind Ellies Garage.

Chubby enemies are good for obtaining legendary weapons, particularly ones that are only dropped by chubbies such as:

- The Shredifier assault rifle
- Bunny rocket launcher
- Whiskey Tango Foxtrot booster shield
- Bouncing Bonnie grenade mod
- Quasar shield
- Legendary class mods.

This is just naming some of the loot I've retrieved from chubby enemies.  Don't get disappointed if they don't drop a legendary the first time because it is a definite that they will drop at least a good purple or e-tech weapon. But be aware, more players = better loot. And it is better if you have some vault hunters relics. Even if you have 3 other characters idle.

Answer (score 1):

Another great thing to do instead of farming chubbies is to go the the Wildlife exploitation preserve, and if you don't do the quest where you pick up the audio diaries for tannis (Basically don't pick up any of them) You can open the boxes toward the place where you find bloodwing and you'll always get the chance to kill a loot midget for every box, up to 4 at a time. Then if you just go into the Hyperion arena, Save and quit, you'll start there and only have to fight through maybe two rooms to do it again. It's a great way to get OP 8 class mods and Relics.

Answer (score 0):

In three horns valley, a chubby skag will spawn near the Happy Pig where the other skag spawn. I've encountered quite a few chubbies. The one I encountered in Three Horns Valley have me the legendary shield Whisky Tango Foxtrot (WTF). I don't know how to see my overall play-time in the game, but I'll estimate around 50 hours. The spawn rate for this chubby is unknown to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try Three Horns Valley. I've been Chubby farming the Skags there and have found 6 or seven in the last 2 days. Just grab a vehicle and drive to all the places that Skags spawn.

Answer (score -2):

if you go to the area with tiny tina i cant remember the name, go to the farmhouse, i use it because of shelter from their attacks, and if let all the varkids pod you will have a good chance, i did this for a while and in 4 hours of doing this over and over i found 5 or 6 of them this is a really good method of finding them